# How to clone DOM structure, and javaScript calculations to work on the clones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I created some code that goes inside a class .card, and also a javascript function that clones this card.
Inside the card has another function that executes a simple calculation. The trouble occurs when I clone the card because the first one works perfectly, but the others don't do any calculations at all.
Another issue I noticed is that the values of the fields on the first card have...well, the values are cloned too, but the intent is to make a pretty empty fields new card.

```
<div id="card" class="card"> 
<!-- And here comes all the card contets -->
</div>

<!-- And here is suposed to hold the new content with no filled fiels but with calcutations woking -->
<div id="clone"></div>


    //this is supposed to clone the fist card
    function add_card(){
    var theCard = document.getElementById('card');  //takes the HTML id leftSide to the theLeftSide var
    var cardClone = theCard.cloneNode(true);//cloning (float)
    clone.appendChild(cardClone);//cloning (paste)
}


 //And this should be doing some simple calcs
    function calc_item(){
    var val_preco = document.getElementById('preco').value;
    var val_peso = document.getElementById('peso').value;

     var relacao_preco = val_preco / val_peso;
     document.getElementById('preco_grama').innerHTML = (relacao_preco);
    }
```

So...What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The complete thing is on http://www.comprebarato.ml/app/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem is you can't repeat ID's in a page...they are unique by definition

You can use [`document.querySelector(cssSelector)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get the first match in a page.  In this case can use the class "card" as selector

In following I stored an initial clone. Then clone that each time a  new one is needed. Then you can modify the content of the clone as needed.

For the calculations  use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get a collection of elements to iterate over. Not knowing what your calcs are I just add up all the numbers in all the cards to show it working

```js
var cardCount = 1

// store a clone right away
var storedClone = document.querySelector('.card').cloneNode(true);

function add_card() {
  //clone the original clone
  var cardClone = storedClone.cloneNode(true); //cloning (float)
  //update content of clone
  cardClone.textContent = 'Card ' + (++cardCount);
  clone.appendChild(cardClone); //cloning (paste)
}


function calc_item() {
  var total = 0;
  var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
  cards.forEach(function(el) {
    total += +/\d+/.exec(el.textContent);
  });
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = 'Card total = ' + total;
}
```

```css
#clone {
  border: 2px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<button onclick="add_card()">Add card</button> <button onclick="calc_item()">Calc</button>

<div id="total">Card total = 1</div>



<!-- And here is suposed to hold the new content with no filled fiels but with calcutations woking -->
<div id="clone">
<div class="card">
  Card 1
</div>
</div>
```